# C insert a string or(char*) in a dynamic 2D char array, Segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic, allocation

So I need to program a 2-dimensional `char` array that needs to get filled from some Child Processes. I don't know how many lines will be returned at run-time.

I made a program that works well for the first three strings (or `char*`) inserted, but after that I get segmentation fault errors. The array should keep the values/strings it has in it. Here's the code:

Global row count:

```
static int rows = 1;
```

Array initialisation:

```
char **output = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1);
output[0] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1023);
output[0][0] = '#';
```

Adding:

```
char foo[1023];
insertArray(output, "bbb");
insertArray(output, foo);
insertArray(output, "bbb");
insertArray(output, "bbb");
```

It actually works fine the first 3 times

Function:

```
static void insertArray(char **c, char *itemToInsert) {

    if (c[0][0] == '#') {
        strncpy(c[0], itemToInsert, 1023);  
    }
    else {

        c = (char **)realloc(c, (rows + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        for (int i = 0; i < rows+1; i++) {
            c[i] = realloc(c[i],sizeof(char) * 1024);
        }
        strcpy(c[rows], itemToInsert);
        rows++;
    }

}
```

I just can't figure out whats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lost result of your reallocation and next time you try to use old pointer to `output`.

You can redesign like this:

```
output = insertArray(output, ...);
output = insertArray(output, ...);
output = insertArray(output, ...);
...

static char **insertArray(char **c, char const *itemToInsert)
{
    ...
    return c;
}
```

Comment: So that means i should make something like a temporary pointer, an reassign it back? How exactly do i do that?

Comment: ok now nothing works anymore, sorry was my fault got a Typo, thanks for the answer, it works like a charm